# Python - No module named "modules"

Tags: python

I am currently trying to import some python files inside of a folder named "modules". My file structure is as follows:

```
src
 - classes
   - modules
   - image generator ( the file where I am trying to import modules)
```

Error:

```py
    from modules.processing import StableDiffusionProcessingTxt2Img, process_images
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules'
```

```py
from modules.processing import StableDiffusionProcessingTxt2Img, process_images
```

I have attempted to add both an `__init__.py` in my `classes` folder, as well as my `modules` folder, but unfortunately that did not resolve any of my problems.

I have verified that the files I am trying to import are infact in my `modules` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to import functions from another python file that's located on another folder, it is having a hard time figuring out where it is located.

Try this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1,'/src/classes/modules')
import (your python file)
```

Make sure you keep the above code on the python file where you are trying to import functions from other .py files

Remember, the path is the absolute path from root. Not sure how many more layers you have before src, put accordingly.

Also, the last line is import python file. So, if you have x.py inside modules, try import x. Then you will be able to use functions inside there.

Answer (score 1):

You must import from the projects' root directory. Assuming src/ is the root directory, you must import as follows:

```
from classes.modules.processing import StableDiffusionProcessingTxt2Img, process_images
```